# Javascript - Why returning array.push(x) from a function doens't push the element x into the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, return, push

I'd like to know why the following function works:

```
function foo(list){
    var array = [];
    array.push(list);
    return array;
}

> foo([1,2,3])
[[1,2,3]]
```

while this one doesn't:

```
function foo(list){
    var  array = [];
    return array.push(list);
}

> foo([1,2,3])
1
```

What's the difference between them?

Comment: Because `push` doesn't return the array you're pushing on to.

Comment: Read the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at the definition of the [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method, it returns the length of the array after the push, not the array itself, that is why it is returning 1.

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and
>   returns the new length of the array.

You are pushing an array with 3 elements to the new array, so in the new array you have an array as its content thus 1 is returned

Comment: Ouch...now I see it. Thank you :)